# Sybase to Oracle table Migration via Migration Wizard offline

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, oracle12c, sybase

How can I create a script of inserts for my sybase to oracle Migration? The Migration wizard only gives me the option to migrate procedures and triggers and such. But there is no select for just tables. When I try to migrate tables offline and move data. the datamove/ folder is empty. I would also want to only migrate specific tables (ones with long identifiers) because i was able to migrate the rest with Copy to Oracle.
I must also note that i do not want to upgrade to an new version of oracle. Currently on ~12.1 so i need to limit the identifiers.

How can I get the offline scripts for table inserts?

Comment: This is a lot of work to just migrate to an Oracle Database version (12.1) that is already years old and out of support. Consider migrating to 19c, then your long identifiers aren't an issue, and you'll be covered for patches/security fixes for the next 3-4 years at least.

Answer (score 0):

You (probably!) don't want INSERTs for offline migration scripts. If you're just running INSERTs, then the online method would probably suffice.

The point of the Offline strategy is to take the data from your Sybase instance to flat, delimited text files (using BCP), which we can THEN use to load back into an Oracle Database using SQLLDR or External Tables which will be EXPONENTIALLY faster than using INSERT scripts.

Take a look at this [whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/migrating-to-oracle-database-wp-3610526.pdf) where I go into offline Sybase migrations in detail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can consider DCO-based Sybase-to-Oracle replication via the Sybase Rep Server. This way, not only will you have all data moved, but you will also be able to have DML updates propagated online, which will make your system switchable live.